# What's the difference between OpenID Provider and OpenID WebRing SSO Provider?

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth, openid-provider

I'm looking at the [DotNetOpenAuth samples](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth.Samples) and there are two OpenID provider samples; and OpenID Provider and an OpenID Web Ring SSO Provider.

Does anyone know the differences between the two, and in which scenario each should be used? I'm specifically looking to see when the Web Ring SSO Provider should be used. I know what the OpenID Provider offers.

To give some context; I need to put together an OpenID provider to provide a single sign-on solution to multiple web apps that I'm working on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SSO sample demonstrates more of what you're looking for, from the sound of it.  The OpenIdProvider is more of an Internet facing provider that serves all relying parties, while the WebRingSSOProvider is targeted at only authenticating users for specific RPs, allowing them to implicitly log the user in if they're already logged in, within a trusted network of sites.